# Is it possible to change the type of some field of a Serializable class in a compatible way?

Tags: java, serialization, enums

To

```
public class SerializableTest implements Serializable
{
    /** field <code>serialVersionUID</code> */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3214128409127377143L;

    private String month;

    private int someInt;

    public String getMonth()
    {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(String month)
    {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getSomeInt()
    {
        return someInt;
    }

    public void setSomeInt(int someInt)
    {
        this.someInt = someInt;
    }
}
```

I have this Serializable class in which there is a String field called month that currently contains a fixed set of constant values - "Jan", "Feb", etc...

I want to refactor the class to have an enum contant instead of String:

```
public enum Month
{
    JAN("Jan"),
    FEB("Feb");

    private final String value;

    Month(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Month fromValue(String v) {
        for (Month c: Month.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this in a compatible way?
I suspect that I'd need to provide a custom serializable form of the enum Month but I'm not really sure how to do it.

Comment: Do you have (a) existing serializations of the class, or (b) a deployment problem such that you can't refresh all instances of the application at the same time?

Comment: Yes, there are already existing serializations. Otherwise I'd just change the implementation and forget about it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be backward compatible you can not change type, but add new field. and update new field after deserialization.

After all data will be migrated you just remove old field.